# No better way to update a record in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I tried many things, but end with this solution to insert a document if it doesn't exists.

```
var filter = DbClientFilterBuilder.BuildFilter(parameters?.Filter);
var db = client.GetDatabase(dbName);
var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(table);
        
var builder = Builders<T>.Update;
List<UpdateDefinition<T>> updates = new List<UpdateDefinition<T>>();
foreach (var propInfo in typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
{
    if (!propInfo.Name.Equals("_id"))
    {
         updates.Add(builder.Set(propInfo.Name, propInfo.GetValue(record)));
    }
    else
    {
         updates.Add(builder.SetOnInsert(propInfo.Name, Guid.NewGuid()));
    }
} 
        
var result = await collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, builder.Combine(updates), new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<T>
{
    IsUpsert = true,
    ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After
});
```

Is this really the only way?
I tried to give the method only the record, but then I got trouble with the Guid and ObjectId thing.

How can I simply insert a document (threadsafe) to the collection, using a Guid as _id written only at the time of insert and don't causing errors if the object is read back?

Comment: Yes, `findOneAndUpdate` is the way to do upserts in mongodb.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, but is it possible to get rid of the GetProperties()-Part?

Comment: That might be the price you have to pay for using C#. In ruby it's much cleaner.